# c# List view focus problem

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview which display the content from the database.I also have a refresh button in my form.Once the refresh button is clicked the listview is get updated once again.The problem is when the refresh button is clicked the already selected item in the listview is get removed from the focus.This is my code

```
       private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to refresh manually
        this.Refresh();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        /*btnEdit_Question.Enabled = true;
        btnRepeat_Question.Enabled = true;
        btnDelete_Question.Enabled = true;*/
        GetData();


    } 

     public void GetData()
    {

        try
        {
            now = DateTime.Now;
            String time_date = now.ToString();
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);
           listView1.Items.Clear();
            myConnection.Open();
            String MyString1 = string.Format("SELECT " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_COLUMN1 + "," + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_COLUMN2 + "," + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_COLUMN3 + "," + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_COLUMN4 + "," + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_COLUMN6 + " FROM " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE);
            com = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = MyString1;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            ListViewItem itmX;
            //Adding the Items To The Each Column
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                itmX = new ListViewItem();
                itmX.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem1 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, dr.GetValue(1).ToString()); //Creating subitems for the parent item
                itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem1);
                //Associating these subitems to the parent item
                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem2 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, dr.GetValue(2).ToString()); //Creating subitems for the parent item

                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem3 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, dr.GetValue(3).ToString()); //Creating subitems for the parent item

                if (dr.GetValue(4).ToString() == "0")
                {
                    aSubFooItem5 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, "No");
                }
                else
                {
                    aSubFooItem5 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, "Yes");
                }

                if (dr.GetDateTime(2) < now && dr.GetDateTime(3) > now)
                {
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem2);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem3);
                    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem4 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, "In Progress");
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem4);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem5);
                  }
                else if (dr.GetDateTime(2) <= now)
                {

                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem2);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem3);
                    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem4 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, "Expired");
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem4);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem5);
                 }
                else if (dr.GetDateTime(2) > now)
                {

                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem2);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem3);
                    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem aSubFooItem4 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmX, "Not Expired");
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem4);
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(aSubFooItem5);
                }
                //add all the items ti listview
                listView1.Items.Add(itmX);
                //Adding colors
                itmX.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
                {
                    if (lvi.SubItems[4].Text=="Expired")
                    {

                       lvi.SubItems[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else if (lvi.SubItems[4].Text == "Not Expired")
                    {
                        itmX.SubItems[4].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itmX.SubItems[4].BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                }

            }
            EventLog log = new EventLog(data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_LOG_EVENT);
            try
            {

                log.Source = data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_LOG_SOURCE;

                log.WriteEntry(data_variables.REX_TXT_STRING_MESSAGE_SUCCESSFUL, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
         if (listView_Selected_Index > -1)
        {

                //Keep the focus in the listview
               this.listView1.Items[listView_Selected_Index].Focused = true;


        }

          private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        now = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {


         //Selecting the each values of the selected item from listview


         listView_Selected_Index = listView1.SelectedIndices[i];

        }
     }
```

Can anyone help me how to remain the focus on the listview item even the refresh button is get clicked

Answer (score 1):

You are removing original (some selected) items from the listview at the top of GetData().
You need to store somewhere what is selected before you read new data from database. Then after new data is displayed in listview you have to select items based on what was selected before data refresh.

```
//store selected items (id or sth else that identifies item)
GetData();
//restore selection (some of previously items may no longer exist)
```

In your code you only saving the last selected item not all of them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    //Selecting the each values of the selected item from listview

    // here You are only saving last selected item
    // instead of this do sth like
    // selectedItems.Add(sth that identifies this item, not index)
    listView_Selected_Index = listView1.SelectedIndices[i];
}
```

Also instead of doing it on every selectedIndexchanged You can do it only before data refresh unless you need it for some other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, save the currently selected index of `ListView1` in some temporary field and after calling `GetData()` method reset the selected index property of `ListView1` by assigning value of temporary field to `ListView1.SelectedIndex` property

something like this:

```
private int _selectedIndex = -1;

private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedIndex = listView1.SelectedIndex;
        //to refresh manually
        this.Refresh();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        /*btnEdit_Question.Enabled = true;
        btnRepeat_Question.Enabled = true;
        btnDelete_Question.Enabled = true;*/
        GetData();
        listView1.SelectexIndex = _selectedIndex;


    }
```

Comment: a temporary variable to save the last selected index, with last i mean selected index before calling ListView1.Items.Clear

Comment: It should be method local variable. And many items can be selected.

Comment: In addition to Peri's comment, you'd be wise not to store /restore using "selectedIndex". If an item was added in the list before the position of your selectedItem, you'll have selected the wrong one. 
You'd be better of storing a unique property for each selected item (so in a list).

Comment: I am saving the last selected index in my code like  listView_Selected_Index = listView1.SelectedIndices[i];How to use this variable to remain the focus in the same item in listview

Comment: If i use SelectexIndex in my code it says an error              Error 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try ListView1.Items[i].Selected = true;